# Firebase is not sending OTP code on my Phone number | Java | Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to authenticate user with phone number using the firebase Authentication method. But it is showing me error after some time by running the code. And I think the sendVerificationCodeToUser() function is not working properly.

```
package com.example.foodapp;

import ...

public class PhoneVerification<phoneAuthProvider> extends AppCompatActivity {

    String verificationCodeBySystem;
    Button btn_verify;
    EditText phoneenteredbyuser;
    ProgressBar progressbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_verification);

        btn_verify = findViewById(R.id.btn_verify);
        phoneenteredbyuser = findViewById(R.id.txt_otp);
        progressbar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        String phoneNo = getIntent().getStringExtra("phone");
        sendVerificationCodeToUser(phoneNo);

        btn_verify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String code= phoneenteredbyuser.toString();

                if(code.isEmpty() || code.length()< 6){
                    phoneenteredbyuser.setError("Wrong OTP...");
                    phoneenteredbyuser.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                verifyCode(code);
            }
        });


    }

    private void sendVerificationCodeToUser(String phoneNo) {
        FirebaseAuth mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        PhoneAuthOptions options =
                PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                        .setPhoneNumber("+92" + phoneNo)       // Phone number to verify
                        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                        .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                        .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                        .build();
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);

    }

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override  //Entering OTP by manual way
        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

            verificationCodeBySystem = s;
        }

        @Override   // Automatically Verifying the OTP by system.
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
            if (code != null) {
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                verifyCode(code);
            }
        }

        @Override  //In case of error this code will run.
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(PhoneVerification.this, "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    };

    private void verifyCode(String codeByUser) {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationCodeBySystem, codeByUser);
        signInUserByCredentials(credential);
    }


    private void signInUserByCredentials(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(PhoneVerification.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Toast.makeText(PhoneVerification.this, "Your Account has been created successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            //Perform Your required action here to either let the user sign In or do something required
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), User_Home.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(PhoneVerification.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have an error message, copy it into the question and indicate which line of code caused it.  Please edit the question to show these debugging details.

Comment: What is the error ? Can you attach the error ?

Comment: Code is directly jumping to the onVerificationFailed() function and showing me the toast "Error Occured"...which I have setted. As well as it is not reading the onVerificationCompleted() function.... Because system is not sending OTP on Phone Number.